# How to filter out exact phrases in an email filter?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I'm getting a bunch of spam emails along the lines of "Iphone, Get our new loans", "Iphone, subscribe to magazine" from completely different senders every single time, but the title is always a variant of:

> Iphone, xxxxxx

I've been trying to filter emails like this in the Y! Email filter and can't seem to find a way to filter an exact phrase.

The issue is, if I try to filter emails containing `Iphone,` it filters all emails that has the word Iphone in it, including legitimate emails. When I try to filter an exact phrase, like `"Iphone,"`, or `'Iphone'`, it doesn't work.

How can I filter out exact phrases in an email filter?

Answer (score 3):

For a single phrase, you should wrap it in double quotation marks.

`"6 new updates and 2 invitations waiting for you on"`

If you have multiple exact phrases to test, use double quotes for each phrase, inserting a space between phrases to separate them (as opposed to a comma).

`"e-statement Notification Account Statement on" "08" 2009`